# Bilinear Tensor Product in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm working on re-implementing [this paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5028-reasoning-with-neural-tensor-networks-for-knowledge-base-completion.pdf) and the key operation is a bilinear tensor product. I hardly know what that means, but the paper has a nice little graphic, which I understand.

[image]

The key operation is **e_1 * W * e_2**, and I want to know how to implement it in tensorflow, because the rest *should* be easy.

Basically, given 3D tensor W, slice it into matrices, and for the j'th slice (a matrix), multiply it on each side by **e_1** and **e_2**, resulting in a scalar, which is the jth entry in the resulting vector (the output of this operation).

So I want to perform a product of **e_1**, a d-dimensional vector, **W**, the d x d x k tensor, and **e_2**, another d-dimensional vector. Could this product be expressed concisely in TensorFlow as it is now, or would I have to define my own op somehow?

**EARLIER EDITS**

Why doesn't multiplying these tensors work, and is there some way to define it more explicitly so that it works?

```py
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.InteractiveSession()
>>> a = tf.ones([3, 3, 3])
>>> a.eval()
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]], dtype=float32)
>>> b = tf.ones([3, 1, 1])
>>> b.eval()
array([[[ 1.]],

       [[ 1.]],

       [[ 1.]]], dtype=float32)
>>>
```

The error message is

```py
ValueError: Shapes TensorShape([Dimension(3), Dimension(3), Dimension(3)]) and TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None)]) must have the same rank
```

**CURRENTLY**

Turns out that multiplying two 3D tensors doesn't work either with `tf.matmul`, so but `tf.batch_matmul` does. `tf.batch_matmul` will also do 3D tensors and matrices. Then I tried 3D and a vector:

```py
ValueError: Dimensions Dimension(3) and Dimension(1) are not compatible
```

Comment: you can do this with a simple reshape.

Comment: Did you end up implementing the paper?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with a simple reshape. For the first of the two matrix multiplies, you have k*d, length d vectors to dot product with.

This should be close:

```
temp = tf.matmul(E1,tf.reshape(Wddk,[d,d*k]))
result = tf.matmul(E2,tf.reshape(temp,[d,k]))
```

Comment: is there no "cleaner" way of doing this? It bothers me aesthetically that I would have to do all these reshapes, but if that's what I have to do...

How are reshapes implemented in tensorflow? Do they move all the values around, or is it just a schema for reading the values out?

Comment: I think they probably just change the 'schema' aka strides, like in numpy. That's [super-powerful](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#view-as-windows). They hint at this in the docs for [conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/nn.html#conv2d). I don't think there's an easier way to say this until [216](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/216) or [175](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/175) are fixed. `einsum('i,j,ijk',E,E,W)` !

Comment: Reshapes in TensorFlow reuse the same data without a copy. But TensorFlow does not use strides -- tensors are always stored in row-major order.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a rank 3 tensor and a vector multiplication between W and e2 which yields a 2D array and then multiply the result with e1. The following function makes use of tensor product and tensor contraction to define the this product (e.g. W * e3)

```
import sympy as sp

def tensor3_vector_product(T, v):
    """Implements a product of a rank 3 tensor (3D array) with a 
       vector using tensor product and tensor contraction.

    Parameters
    ----------
    T: sp.Array of dimensions n x m x k

    v: sp.Array of dimensions k x 1

    Returns
    -------
    A: sp.Array of dimensions n x m

    """
    assert(T.rank() == 3)
    # reshape v to ensure a 1D vector so that contraction do 
    # not contain x 1 dimension
    v.reshape(v.shape[0], )
    p = sp.tensorproduct(T, v)
    return sp.tensorcontraction(p, (2, 3))
```

You can verify this multiplication by using the examples provided in [ref](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/07070111X?journalCode=siread). The above function contracts the second and third axis, in your case I think you should contract (1, 2) because W is defined as d x d x k and not k x d x d as in my case.